# AVAudioUnitEQ: numberOfBands parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioengine

when i initialize a AVAudioUnitEQ one parameter is the number of bands, which the equalizer Unit will have.

My Question is what ist the possible max number of bands?  is the number limited to the specific device I am using? (thats how it works on Android i think)

Or is the number of bands on iOS completely individually depending on how many bands I want to have?

[Link to the AVAudioUnitEQ init method in API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiouniteq)

I have looked in all threads I have found, but nowhere is this this topic clarified.

Thank you!

Comment: The maximum number of bands appears to be 16